# Is there any straightforward way to apply a logical operator on a Perl array?

Tags: arrays, perl, logical-operators

I'm looking for something like this:
(where `OR` is my hypothetical built-in function)

Code:

```
@x=(1, 0, 1, 1, 1);
$a=OR(@x);
print $a;
```

Expected result:

```
1
```

Is this possible with Perl?

Comment: do you expect boolean, or first `true` value from `@x`?

Comment: `$a = grep $_, @x;` is the quick version.

Comment: `grep` goes through all elements

Comment: @mpapec Yes, it does. But for such a small list, it hardly matters. Optimization is a fine exercise, but premature optimization is usually a waste of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sub any { $_ && return 1 for @_; 0 }
```

Taken from: `List::Util`'s [Suggested Additions](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#SUGGESTED-ADDITIONS)  section.

Also, the `all` function on that section would correspond to an AND operator, so on.

Comment: All the answers are very much appreciated. I'm selecting this answer since it's the simplest way to get the thing done. `any` is logical `OR`, `all` is logical `AND`.

Answer (score 10):

How about [List::Util reduce](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html)

```
use List::Util qw(reduce);
my $foo = reduce { $a or $b } (1,0);
say $foo;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sub OR {
    foreach (@_) {
        return 1 if $_;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Though it's a good idea to avoid all-capital identifiers.

Comment: I like your solution better. Mine evaluates the whole List. :\

Answer (score 0):

You could *make* this function pretty easily:

```
sub OR { 
   my ($first, @rest) = @_; 

   for (@rest) {
      $first ||= $_;
   }

   return $first; # True(1) or False(0)
}
```

Note: This evaluates the entire list, really you could just stop at the *first* value that was true.